# how to stop google from capturing certain pages on our website, but I still want GA reporting

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, canonical-link

I've noticed that Google is indexing 35k pages on my website, when in reality, there should only be around 2,450.  (It is an ecommerce website, hence so many pages).  I noticed that Google is picking up queries checkout and our quick shop.  It is also picking up multiple pages for certain categories.  We had been working with a developer to fix this using:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.***.com/category/c/***/">
<link rel="next" href="http://www.***.com/**/start/15/" />
```

but it seems not to work, and we are still getting duplicates (page, titles, etc).

So, if you can understand me, I have multiple issues, but I believe they all stem from one another.  Also, if I put a "no-follow" on an internal link, will this cause Google Analytics to stop tracking?

Thank you for your time,
Erynn

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google Analytics is not bothered by nofollow-tags and the SEO question is not programming related (and should probably  go to webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics track trafic to the site current url, so link tags couldn't influence that. Anyways to answer your question, if you want Google not to crawl your page, you should read about robots.txt, that's a file which specifies what search engines (Google) must not crawl. More about it [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en)

Comment: I think I figured out the no-follow issues. I wanted GA to keep tracking, and I think it works fine how I did it. Thank you for confirming my suspicions.  However, that does not fix my biggest issue, the canonical links not being recognized in google and google indexing multiple pages of the same page.  A basic link in my navigation is showing as 97k internal links in google search console.

Answer (score 0):

A `no-follow` only tells search engines not to crawl a link from a page. If they find the same file on a different page, they will still crawl it. This will not stop GA from tracking your site. To prevent GA from tracking a page, remove the relevant scripts from that page.

You can also tell search engine spiders to stop crawling some pages using your [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) file, or by adding `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` to your `<head>` tag.

Additional Reference: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710

Comment: I cannot add a noindex to my category pages, as it will effect everything.

Comment: @ErynnSzewczyk I understand, but I can't think of any other elegant solutions that I have not posted. Have you considered defining the pages you want to block with a specific URL pattern, then using robots.txt?

Comment: We have done that for other areas.  This seems to be related to our categories pages.  Our CMS developers have been charged with fixing this issue for nearly a year now, and we come up with more questions than answers.  Thank you for your time.